# mysql query retrieving number of records for each day for the last 15 days

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database table with user registration records. `Table: [USER]`
One of my columns is named `created_on` with type int and holds a `timestamp` for the registration date and time.

How should I compose my query so I can have the number of registered users for each day?

I want results like this:

```
21/11 : 150 users
22/11 : 200 users
23/11 : 50 users
24/11 : 150 users
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `FROM_UNIXTIME()` and simple date functions.

```
SELECT MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_on)) AS "month", 
    DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_on)) AS "day", COUNT(created_on)
FROM `user`
WHERE YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_on)) = 2012
GROUP BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_on)), DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(created_on))
```

You can do your string formatting using PHP.